# An error occurred while calling o2864.collect

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark

I have a RDD object(bid) that get from map, and then I just do a simple bid.count(). Then I received the following error. Can someone tell me what this error might be? I try to google what it means but got no answer.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0283df3b1938> in <module>()
----> 1 bid.count()

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in count(self)
    706         3
    707         """
--> 708         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
    709 
    710     def stats(self):

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in sum(self)
    697         6.0
    698         """
--> 699         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).reduce(operator.add)
    700 
    701     def count(self):

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in reduce(self, f)
    617             if acc is not None:
    618                 yield acc
--> 619         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    620         return reduce(f, vals)
    621 

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    581         """
    582         with _JavaStackTrace(self.context) as st:
--> 583           bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
    584         return list(self._collect_iterator_through_file(bytesInJava))
    585 

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    535         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    536         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 537                 self.target_id, self.name)
    538 
    539         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/username/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1.0:9 failed 4 times, most recent failure: TID 7 on host 08.bm-hadoope-datanode.dev.lax1 failed for unknown reason
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1207)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

And then I join the bid table with another table, then get a new RDD. It seems going smooth, but when I do first() for this new RDD. I received the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o274.collectPartitions.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9.0:6 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 32 on host 05.bm-hadoope-datanode.dev.lax1: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:629)
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:735)
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
        java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
        java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
        parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:599)
        parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:360)
        parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:100)
        parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:172)
        parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:130)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:122)
        org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:293)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:200)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:175)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:175)
        org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1160)
        org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:174)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1207)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Have you got an exception from `Py4JJava` earlier in your log?

Comment: I don't for this bid.count(). But for after I join tables and do first(). It has an exception failure. I've added this to the original post.

Comment: The reason you don't get an error before running `.first`, is because Spark transformations are lazy. Your error seems to occur in an anonymous function you provide (`$anonfun$run$1`), but I cannot tell from your stack trace which one. Try fetching the line "raw" from Spark, and ensure that you can apply your transformation to it locally, completely bypassing Spark. That should give you a prettier python Exception when your code fails.

Comment: I added a traceback. Is it enough for you to tell what's wrong?